# Polynomial Interpolation and Degree of the Polynomial

Tags: interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

I'm currently studying polynomial interpolation through Newton and Lagrange, and I've generated a polynomial approximation function with the following data points:

```
|  t  |  -1|-0.5 |-0.25|0.25| 0.5|  4|
|f(t) |-637|-96.5|-20.5|20.5|96.5|637|
```

I've generated the following interpolation polynomial with a degree of 5:

p(x) =−29.8236x<sup>5</sup>−29.8236x<sup>4</sup>+ 601.3198x<sup>3</sup>+ 9.3198x<sup>2</sup>+ 44.5340x−0.4659

I have plotted it using SciPy, and this is the graph p(x) generates:
[image]

Why does that behavior happen from t = 0.5 to t = 4?

Is it due to my polynomial being of a high degree? Should I try curve fitting instead?

EDIT: I inverted the table, as I was considering f(t) as t before.

Comment: Are you trying to interpolate $f$ or $f^{-1}$?  Your graph seems to be of $f^{-1}$ because your inputs, $t$, are on the vertical axis and your outputs $f(t)$ are on the horizontal axis...

Comment: Sorry, the table was inverted. I've changed it, and it should now match the graph.

Comment: This is related to [Runge's phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon).

Comment: Thank you. So from what I read, if I understood it, to avoid this I should get more data points near the edges of my interval?